# lodash - how to merge identical object and pushes their primitive value into the respective array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of identical objects like this. I want to merge them into one object, where as only primitive values will be "stacked" into an array while Objects will be traversed and arrays will be concatenated.

I would prefer a functional solution (i can manage fine with for loops,...)

```
const x = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 'hi',
    c: { d: 1 },
    e:[1,2]
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 'there',
    c: { d: 2 },
    e:[3,4]
  }
];

const result = {
  a:[1,2],
  b:['hi','there'],
  c:{
    d:[1,2]
  },
  e:[1,2,3,4]
}
```

In any case hints to which lodash methods to use/chain would be enough for me to puzzle this out. Currently I'm stuck...

Comment: please add where you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) with a customizer method to handle arrays concatenation and primitives. Since `_.mergeWith()` is recursive, it will handle nested objects.

```js
const x = [{"a":1,"b":"hi","c":{"d":1},"e":[1,2]},{"a":2,"b":"there","c":{"d":2},"e":[3,4]}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...x, (ov, sv) => {
  if(Array.isArray(ov)) return ov.concat(sv);
  
  if(ov !== undefined && !_.isObject(ov)) return [ov, sv];
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```